# Finding the probability of a region $D$ given a joint density

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density 
>   $$
> f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> 6y,\ \text{for} \ (x,y)\in D \\
> 0 \ \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $D$ is the triangular region where $x > 0$, $y > 0$, and $x + y < 1$.
>
> Find $P\left(Y \geq \frac{1}{2}(1-X)\right)$

Attempted solution:

I think I am getting the bounds wrong but I get

$$P\left(Y \geq \frac{1}{2}(1-X)\right) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{(1-x)/2} 6y dydx$$

which equals $1/4$ but the answer is $3/4$. I drew the picture and I am really not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the limits of your integral, you're actually computing $P\left(Y \leq \frac{1}{2}(1-X)\right)$.

Comment: I see so if I subtract 1 from answer I am done I think that works? In other words, $P\left(Y \geq \frac{1}{2}(1-X)\right) = 1 - P\left(Y<\frac{1}{2}(1-X)\right)$

Comment: Perhaps you can show me how to get the correct bounds then?

Comment: subtracting the answer from $1$ works

Comment: If you'd prefer the direct approach, then

Comment: $$
\int_0^1 \int_{(1-x)/2}^{1-x} 6y\,dy\,dx
$$

Comment: you need to break it in two...